# Rails 7.0.4 API App with Devise throwing DisabledSessionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest

I am developing a Rails 7.0.4 API only application where I am using Devise to log in a Cinema owner to update and edit cinema's billboard.

I am facing an error when simple testing with MiniTest:

```rb
test "should get index" do
  sign_in users(:one)
  get movies_url, as: :json
  assert_response :success
end
```

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionDispatch::Request::Session::DisabledSessionError: Your application has sessions disabled. To write to the session you must first configure a session store
    test/controllers/movies_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:MoviesControllerTest>'
test/controllers/movies_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:MoviesControllerTest>'
```

I have already searched for this issue on Github on this link (https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5443) and I have already tried to have in application.rb the following:

```rb
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```

and also I have tried to have this fix

```rb
module RackSessionFixController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class FakeRackSession < Hash
    def enabled?
      false
    end
  end

  included do
    before_action :set_fake_rack_session_for_devise
    
    private

    def set_fake_rack_session_for_devise
      request.env['rack.session'] ||= FakeRackSession.new
    end
  end
end
```

but it does not work either. Note this happens only when unit testing with MiniTest. I am testing a controller (Movies) in which is required to be logged in to make any operations (such as create, update and delete).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue. In my case, it was the autosign process after the password reset that was causing the error. I tried all the solutions you describe and, like you, it never worked for me. Here's how I solved my problem easily, and preserve the api only mode.

```rb
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.sign_in_after_reset_password = false
```

```rb
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json }, only: [:passwords, :sessions]
```

If in this particular case, the problem isn't directly related to autosign, perhaps simply adding the sessions to the routes can be enough.